# react native navigator render method error

Tags: javascript, react-native

Update:

The error message goes like this:

Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function, but got object. Please check the render method of 'Navigator'.

I am new to javascript and react native, any suggestion will be grateful.

```
class testiOS extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{name: 'home'}}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
      />
    );
  }

  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.name === 'home') {
      return(<Home navigator={navigator} />);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the Home component:

```
 class Home extends Component {

   render() {
     return(
       <View>
         <TextInput
           placeholder="Input and click search"
         />
       </View>
     );
   }

 }
```

Comment: Did you try: `this._renderScene.bind(this)` ?

Comment: yes, it's a typo, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo. Instead of `initalRoute`  should be `initialRoute`

Comment: for god shake, thanks so much. Now it has a new error, it says my render method of Navigator is an object, not a string/class/function. any idea?

Comment: @castiel i'm not sure, may be it is somehow related to your `Home` component render method.. In my opinion , you should post it as a new question

Comment: turns out, I forget to exports it.